# Drupal - Show block on all term pages for one vocabulary

Tags: drupal

How can I make a block show up on all term pages for a specific vocabulary.

Im assuming this can be done somehow with the php visibility settings? I only want the block to show up on term pages, not on pages of nodes tagged with those terms.

Thanks

Comment: Ive found this link but it doesn't work for me: http://drupal.org/node/706336#comment-4327656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend checking out the Context module, which allows you to control block visibility, as well as lots of other "contextual" type data from a simple interface.

Comment: Looks powerful. Im surprised their isnt a php snippet for block visibility though. Thanks

Comment: the panel module may fit as well